# What material can I lay over a capacitive touch screen to block its operation, while still allowing me to see it?

Tags: touchscreen, capacitive

I own a Kindle Voyage and would like to be able to hold it anywhere, not just along the edges, while reading.  So I'm looking for a material that's clear to read through, relatively lightweight, and that will block the touchscreen sensor from registering my touches.  What material can I cut to size for this purpose?

Comment: Thick layer of clear acrylic? (several mm). I can't think of anything that would be specifically anti-capacitative and also cheap and easily available.

Comment: @pjc50 Yes -- I had some scrap acrylic laying around, and it works like a charm!  Thank you!